# Close Form2 from Form3, that has been opened in Form1

Tags: c#, winforms

So, i'm working on a little Game. 
The "Game.cs" opens the Win-Screen ("winscreen.cs"). The Winscreen gives you the ability to create a New Game. The Game.cs was opened trough the MainMenu.

If you click the New-Game Button on the Winscreen, it opens up a new Playfield:

```
private void winscreen_again_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Game loadGame = new Game();
    loadGame.Show();
}
```

The Problem is: It opens up the new Playfield, and the old one, that once was opened trough the MainMenu stays open. So i tried `loadGame.Close();` which does nothing.

I also tried to do this in my Form1.cs (The MainMenu):

```
public Game loadGame;
```

and call this later:

```
this.loadGame = new Game();   
this.loadGame.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
this.loadGame.Show();
```

To close the Window from the Winscreen.cs i did this in the Winscreen:

```
Game.loadGame.Close();
```

and because that didnt worked, i did

```
Game closeGame = new Game();
closeGame.loadGame.Close();
```

but that did not work either, and if i set the `public Game loadGame;` to "static" the this.loadGame... wouldnt work anymore.

So how do i close the existing Game.cs trough my Winscreen.cs?
Thanks!

Comment: Surely you have to make your Game object a member variable of the winscreen class? Otherwise, each click you do it just starts a new instance. But if you had a m_loadGame variable you could test if it is already  displayed. Those are my thoughts.

Comment: Your `loadGame` variable was declared inside the `winscreen_again_Click` handler. So you can't do `Game.loadGame.Close`. You have to add the `Game m_loadGame` variable to the actual `winscreen` class itself.

Comment: you could pass the old playfield from the main menu to the constructor of the winscreen. This way you would have the instance of the window that was formerly shown. You still would need a class variable like Andrew said. In the constructor you could assign the parameter that you got from the `main.cs` and close it in the `winschreen_again_Click` handler before opening a new one

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Could you post an extended Version with code please? 
If I declare `Game loadGame = new Game();` outside of the OnClick, i still can't call it with `Game.loadGame.Close();`.

@MongZhu Can you please make an advanced Answer on that too? It seems to be logical, but since I'm new to C# I'm a bit confused.

Thanks to all of you in advance!

Comment: could you post at least the partial code of the three WinForms Classes that are involved in your example. That would make it easier for me to make an appropriate / advanced answer

Comment: @MongZhu Sure thing! Even better, I just link you my Repo, the Code you need is in Winscreen.cs and Form1.cs. I just uploaded the Preparation for the thing i want: https://github.com/DanielKng/Tic-Tac-Toe

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class Winscreen : Form
{
    // Variable to catch the old playfield
    Game oldPlayfield;

    // the old playfield is passed in the constructor
    public Winscreen(Game opf)
    {
        this.oldPlayfield = opf;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void winscreen_again_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Game loadGame = new Game();
        loadGame.Show();

        // close the old field
        this.oldPlayfield.Close();
    }
// rest of the class
}
```

In `Game.cs` inside the CheckWinner method you would call the Winscreen like this:

```
//Shows the winner Animation and changes the Text to the Winning player
Winscreen loadWinscreen = new Winscreen(this);
```

Unfortunately I cannot test it now to verify whether it would work.
This is also not the cleanest solution.
2.nd option:
I would suggest rather to have a boolean property `repeatGame` that can be set to true in `Winscreen.cs` when the user presses the `winscreen_again` Button. Create a property of type `Winscreen` inside `Game.cs` and subscribe to the `Closing` event in the constructor of `Game`.
Inside the eventhandler you could ask whether the `repeatGame` flag has been set and if so you could just clear the playfield and start a new game.

Comment: Oh my God! Thank you so much!
Is it okay if I link your Profile in the Code? And...please add a Email to your account, or contact me with the E-Mail provided on my Github ;)
Thank you!

Comment: glad to hear that it worked. Yes you can link my profile.